# Type Mismatch Unit and String in Scala

Tags: scala, list, for-loop, tuples, list-comprehension

I am trying to take from a list of tuples (e.g. `List[(String, String)]`) some words that have the difference between the number of syllables smaller than 2.

If that is ok, I return them - however, I have some issues: I get `Unit` found and `String` expected.

```
   def ecrire():String = {
     // Choose deux output: List[(Word, Word)]
     // I take every tuple of the list and proceed as the element "b"
       for (b <- choose_deux()){
           val x = b._1
           val y = b._2
           val diff = Math.abs(x.syllabes - y.syllabes)

           // Check if difference between syllables is smaller than 2
           if(diff <= 2)
               return x.toString() + "\n" + y.toString()
       }
   }
}
```

Now I know that probably I have to do a yield at the bottom, but yield what exactly? The idea is that if the condition shown in the "if" is respected, I write the string made of these two elements.

The error is shown at the for loop: `type mismatch; found: Unit; required: String`

Could you please help me a bit? I am still new and learning!

Comment: Some default (string) return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type mismatch error is because your for loop doesn't have else statement and you can't return using if inside a for loop. So for loop is not returning anything so scala compiler assumes the return type to be () i.e. unit() and you have defined the return type as String.

Defining the functions in the following way should solve your issue

```
  def diff(x) = Math.abs(x._1.syllabes - x._2.syllabes)

  for (b <- choose_deux() if(diff(b) <= 2)) yield b._1.toString() + "\n" + b._2.toString()
```